# Getting data from the Database

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I am designing a web page, i want to get last entry from the column ("call_id) from the table "tbl_CALL" and store in the variable("lastcallId").
can anyone help me for writing he code in c#.
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you already have TNSNAMES.ORA defined on your machine that connects to your oracle database?

Comment: I'm new into all these. Connection is already given to me

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? at least the codes.

Comment: string lastcall;
                string SQLlastcall = "SELECT last(call_no) FROM tbl_IThelpdesk";
                myOdbcCommand.CommandText = SQLlastcall;
                OdbcDataReader myOdbcDataReader = myOdbcCommand.ExecuteReader();
                lastcall = myOdbcDataReader.Read();

Comment: Here i want the last callID into the variable "lastcall". Is it the correct code? does read() give the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
on your *web.config*:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDBConnString" connectionString="Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=[database];User ID=[userID];Password=[yourPassword];"
   providerName="System.Data.OleDB" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

in your C#:

```
private OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
private string _strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleDBConnString"].ConnectionString;
private OleDbTransaction _trans = null;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

conn.Open();

strSelectQuery = "SELECT last(call_no) FROM tbl_IThelpdesk"; // here you have to put your query


da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSelectQuery, conn);
da.Fill(ds);
dt = ds.Tables[0];

conn.Close();
```

Now, the content of your SQL query is now at `dt`. I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using the same method for my current project. Although I'm using N-tier method, I don't know if you're familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions here such as which technology are you using in C# (ADO.net, Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc.)?  Also, it is not clear if the call_id column is asending order.  Assuming the key is auto generated and is always ascending, you could write an SQL statement like the following to get the max out.

SELECT MAX(call_id) as "last_call_id" FROM mytable;

Without knowing which technology you are using, it is hard to help more.

Comment: ASP.NET is the web framework, not the database framework.